# LibGDX 3D collision detection

Tags: 3d, libgdx, collision-detection

I am using LibGDX game engine to create 2d games and box2d for physics. How can I check for collisions? Is there sth like box2d for 3d games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there sth like box2d for 3d games?

Yeah. There is a 3d physics engine in libgdx called [Bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/). Written in C C++ it uses a [wrapper](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/extensions/gdx-bullet) to be able to communicate with it from java.

To add it to your project, you must add this to your gradle.build file in your project root directory:

**Core Dependency:**

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
```

**Desktop Dependency:**

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```

**Android Dependency:**

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
```

**iOS Dependency:**

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
```

**HTML Dependency: Not compatible!**

How to create a game with it is a very broad question. Take a look at this:

[Libgdx Bullet Physics](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bullet-physics)

Comment: @user3693550 you should also take a look at Xoppas blog: http://blog.xoppa.com  the latest 2 tutorials cover the bullet library